# Google Guava / providing functional collection-type implementations

Tags: java, clojure, guava

Does someone know if Guava or Java8 in the future will provide persistent collection-implementations inspired by more functional implementations as for instance in Clojure or Scala (providing snapshots, efficient modifications due to sharing of tree-structures and so on)?

Comment: I am wondering what are the real-world use cases for a persistent collection?

Comment: Persistent collections are used extensively in functional programming which favors immutability. In this case, "persistent" does not mean "save to disk", but rather, "when a change is made, make a (partial) copy and change the copy" The original data structure remains completely unchanged, and is therefore implicitly thread-safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regards to Guava, there is a discussion on the project's discussion group [here](http://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1b813f1e0f461afd/0e2126c045da1c12?lnk=gst&q=persistent#0e2126c045da1c12), which ends with the project lead (Kevin Bourrillion) stating his opinion that Guava would not be the correct library for persistent collections.

I don't believe there's anything like this scheduled for Java 8. A description of the plan for Java 8 [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/), which states the main features are Project Jigsaw, and Lambda. There will be other inclusions, but no mention of persistent collections.

Answer (score 2):

Check out PCollections: http://code.google.com/p/pcollections/

I expect it's the closest to what you're looking for.